# Startup() confused while converting class:IExtension into class:BaseToolbar

Tags: c#, arcgis-10.4

I developed an extension with ArcGIS 10.4.1 that I can use through the extension menu and now I need it as a toolbar. The problem is that ArcGIS launches only the startup() event from the extension and not my newly added BaseToolBar.startup()

```
/// <summary>
/// Classe d'extension pour le contexte
/// </summary>
[Guid("4600d1fb-cac2-4f6d-a726-261abe40dfad")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Mrn.Taktik.ControleGis.ContexteExtension")]
public class ContexteExtension : IExtension, IExtensionConfig, IPersistVariant
{
       .  .  .  Parameters and Access variables  .  .  .

    public void Startup(ref object initializationData)
    {
        this.application = initializationData as IApplication;
        this.appStatus = this.application as IApplicationStatus;

        if (this.application != null)
        {
            contexteTakTik = ContexteTakTik.Instance;
            contexteTakTik.Initialiser(new IntPtr(this.application.hWnd));
            //// Wireup the events
            this.SetupEvents();
        }
    }

       .  .  .  #region COM Registration Functions  .  .  .
}
```

At this point, I simply created a BaseToolbar and copied what was inside my class into the new one. The only way to to amke it work right now is if I keep included the extension class as it is the only way for my code to enter Startup(). I tried to look online where it is first called but couldnt find anything. I need my code to go through BarreOutils.Startup() and not ContexteExtension.Startup().

```
/// <summary>
/// Description for ArcGISToolbar1.
/// </summary>
[Guid("bfeb9989-0c45-4db4-b12d-310efaa5d787")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("Mrn.Taktik.ControleGis.ArcGISToolbar1")]
public sealed class BarreOutils : BaseToolbar
{
.  .  .  Parameters and Access variables  .  .  .

    public void Startup(ref object initializationData)
    {
        this.application = initializationData as IApplication;
        this.appStatus = this.application as IApplicationStatus;

        if (this.application != null)
        {
            contexteTakTik = ContexteTakTik.Instance;
            contexteTakTik.Initialiser(new IntPtr(this.application.hWnd));
            //// Wireup the events
            this.SetupEvents();
        }
    }

       .  .  .  #region COM Registration Functions  .  .  .
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through some other tools built and apparently you need your tools to work also as an extension and by that i mean, having both classes included in the project, concerning the problem I was having, I used only one or the other when in fact i needed both. There may be some deeper reasoning on why you need both and maybe there's also a possibility to have only one or the other but in my case, i do need both to work properly.

Comment: By having both, I then made sure to remove all the functions that were doubled from the extension class and the toolbar class.